# Could someone explain this benchmarking function from 'Learning Python'

Tags: python, function, time

I'm learning python with the book 'Learning Python' by Mark Lutz. I have a question concerning this benchmarking functions. I understand the workings of the first two functions, but I don't quite understand the last function. Could someone explain to me the exact workings of the last function and the result it returns? According to the author it's a combination of the first two functions. It returns the best of totals times - the lowest time among a specified amount of runs to compute the time to call a specific function x  times. I understand his explanation but I do not understand the tuple the bestoftotal function returns. Could someone explain to me this tuple?

```
# File timer.py
"""
Homegrown timing tools for function calls.
Does total time, best-of time, and best-of-totals time
"""

import time, sys
try:
    timer = time.perf_counter
except AttributeError:
    timer = time.clock if sys.platform[:3] == 'win' else time.time

def total(reps, func, *pargs, **kargs):
    """
    Total time to run func() reps times.
    Returns (total time, last result)
    """
    repslist = list(range(reps))
    start = timer()
    for i in repslist:
        ret = func(*pargs, **kargs)
    elapsed = timer() - start
    return (elapsed, ret)

def bestof(reps, func, *pargs, **kargs):
    """
    Quickest func() among reps runs.
    Returns (best time, last result)
    """
    best = 2 ** 32
    for i in range(reps):
        start = timer()
        ret = func(*pargs, **kargs)
        elapsed = timer() - start
        if elapsed < best: best = elapsed
    return (best, ret)

def bestoftotal(reps1, reps2, func, *pargs, **kargs):
    """
    Best of totals:
    (best of reps1 run of (total of reps2 run of func))
    """
    return bestof(reps1, total, reps2, func, *pargs, **kargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bestoftotal` returns a call to the function `bestof` with `total` as the func argument.

---

You said you understood the first two functions, but let me explain again for the sake of my own understanding.

All the *pargs and **kargs can make things a bit confusing. To simplify, let's say I want to benchark `myFunction()`, which take no arguments.

To measure the total time it takes to run `myFunction` 10 times, I do:

```
total(10, myFunction)
```

To measure the best of 5 trials (1 trial = 1 run of `myFunction`), I do:

```
bestof(5, myFunction)
```

---

Now, I want to know the best of 5 trial, one trial consisting of running the function 10 times ("the best of total trials").
One trial is actually one run of the function `total(10, myFunction)`
So the best of 5 trial would be `bestof(5, total(10,my Function))`

This last line is not a valid call in Python. That's where the *pargs and **kwargs are usefull.
When you call `bestof(5, total, 10, myFunction)`, the arguments 10 and `myFunction` are pass along when calling `total`:
The line `ret = func(*pargs, **kargs)` becomes `ret = total(10, myFunction)`.

So what does `bestoftotal` do ? Well, it takes two numbers reps1 and reps 2 (in my example, 5 and 10), and the function to benchmark. It returns a call to the function `bestof`.

`bestoftotal(5, 10, myFunction)` will call `bestof(5, total, 10, myFunction)`, which will itself call 5 times `total(10, myFunction)`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, the last function is comprehensible now :)